# How to center subfigures in a 2 by 2 subfigmatrix

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subfloats

I have a figure with 4 subfigures displayed in a 2 by 2 matrix

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{subfigmatrix}{2}
        \subfigure[ALS1]{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm,keepaspectratio]{fig1.png}}
        \subfigure[ALS2]{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm,keepaspectratio]{fig2.png}}
        \subfigure[Hepatitis1]{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm,keepaspectratio]{fig3.png}}
        \subfigure[Hepatitis2]{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm,keepaspectratio]{fig4.png}}
    \end{subfigmatrix}
    \caption{Baseline accuracy (several classifiers and number of observations).}
    \label{fig:baseline}
 \end{figure}
```

and it looks like this

[image]

How can I have the images closer to the center of the page, instead of them using the whole width of the page? Basically they would be in the space that is now empty...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** (2014/10/16) A second approach is use of `patchcmd` from `etoolbox` to patch the `\hfill` command embedded in `subfigmatrix` because the `\hfill` is used to evenly allocate the figures in a row.

[image]

Code

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{}{graphicx}
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[papersize={20cm,25cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigmat}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}


Before

\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{subfigmatrix}{3}
   \subfigure[ALS1]{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}
   \subfigure[ALS2]{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}
   \subfigure[ALS1]{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}
   \subfigure[Hepatitis1]{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}
   \subfigure[Hepatitis2]{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}
   \end{subfigmatrix}
   \caption{Baseline accuracy (several classifiers and number of observations.)}
   \label{fig:baseline1}
 \end{figure}

After:

%\patchcmd{<command>}{<code to replace>}{<code>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\subfigmatrix}{\hfill}{\hspace{0.8cm}}{}{}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{subfigmatrix}{3}
   \subfigure[ALS1]{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}
   \subfigure[ALS2]{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}
   \subfigure[ALS1]{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}
   \subfigure[Hepatitis1]{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}
   \subfigure[Hepatitis2]{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}
   \end{subfigmatrix}
   \caption{Baseline accuracy (several classifiers and number of observations.)}
   \label{fig:baseline2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

This is one possibility. Put the `subfigmatrix` environment into an `adjustwidth` environment from `changepage` package. Within an adjustwidth environment the left and right margins can be adjusted. The environment takes two required length arguments:

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{hleftmargini}{hrightmargini}
 content
\end{adjustwidth}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}%,caption}
\usepackage{subfigmat}
\usepackage{changepage}
\begin{document}


Before

\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{subfigmatrix}{2}
   \subfigure[ALS1]{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}
   \subfigure[ALS2]{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}
   \subfigure[Hepatitis1]{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}
   \subfigure[Hepatitis2]{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}
\end{subfigmatrix}
\caption{Baseline accuracy (several classifiers and number of observations.)}
\label{fig:baseline}
\end{figure}

After:

\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{adjustwidth}{2.2cm}{2.2cm}
\begin{subfigmatrix}{2}
   \subfigure[ALS1]{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}
   \subfigure[ALS2]{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}
   \subfigure[Hepatitis1]{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}
   \subfigure[Hepatitis2]{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}
\end{subfigmatrix}
\caption{Baseline accuracy (several classifiers and number of observations.)}
\label{fig:baseline}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```