# Subfigure package misplaces last subfigure in full width environment

Tags: graphics, subfloats

I am using subfigure package along with pdflatex. My paper is in two columns, and sometimes I use a full width figure with subfigures:

```
\begin{figure*}
\subfigure[AM06]{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{AR06_RUN03_vort.png}}
\subfigure[AM07]{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{AR07_RUN03_vort.png}}
\subfigure[AM08]{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{AR08_run03_vort.png}}
\subfigure[AM09]{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{AR09_run03_vort.png}}
\subfigure[AM10]{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{AR10_run03_vort.png}}
\subfigure[AM11]{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{AR11_run03_vort.png}}
\subfigure[AM12]{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{AR12_run03_vort.png}}
\subfigure[AM13]{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{AR13_run03_vort.png}}
\end{figure*}
```

[image: Subfigure wrong placement.]

As you can see from the image, it places the last subfigure in the wrong position. Any ideas on how I can debug this?

Comment: This may help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207302/34618

Comment: This depends a good deal on where you want subfigure (h) to be placed: exactly below subfigure (e), or the last two subfigures centered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the last row to be justified, with subfigure (h) exactly below subfigure (e), then this is a way:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{subfig} % not subfigure!!!
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\setlength{\lineskip}{1ex}% increase spacing
\subfloat[AM06]{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{AR06_RUN03_vort.png}}%
\hspace{.125\textwidth}%
\subfloat[AM07]{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{AR07_RUN03_vort.png}}%
\hspace{.125\textwidth}%
\subfloat[AM08]{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{AR08_run03_vort.png}}%
\hspace{.125\textwidth}%
\subfloat[AM09]{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{AR09_run03_vort.png}}%
\hspace{.125\textwidth}%
\subfloat[AM10]{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{AR10_run03_vort.png}}%
\hspace{.125\textwidth}%
\subfloat[AM11]{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{AR11_run03_vort.png}}%
\hspace{.125\textwidth}%
\subfloat[AM12]{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{AR12_run03_vort.png}}%
\hspace{.125\textwidth}%
\subfloat[AM13]{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{AR13_run03_vort.png}}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Note that `subfigure` has been obsolete for 15 years.

[image]

If you prefer the last two subfigures to be centered in the line, just add `\centering` to the code above:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{subfig} % not subfigure!!!
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\centering
\setlength{\lineskip}{1ex}% increase spacing
\subfloat[AM06]{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{AR06_RUN03_vort.png}}%
\hspace{.125\textwidth}%
\subfloat[AM07]{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{AR07_RUN03_vort.png}}%
\hspace{.125\textwidth}%
\subfloat[AM08]{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{AR08_run03_vort.png}}%
\hspace{.125\textwidth}%
\subfloat[AM09]{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{AR09_run03_vort.png}}%
\hspace{.125\textwidth}%
\subfloat[AM10]{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{AR10_run03_vort.png}}%
\hspace{.125\textwidth}%
\subfloat[AM11]{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{AR11_run03_vort.png}}%
\hspace{.125\textwidth}%
\subfloat[AM12]{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{AR12_run03_vort.png}}%
\hspace{.125\textwidth}%
\subfloat[AM13]{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{AR13_run03_vort.png}}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### A note about `\lineskip`.

When TeX forms a paragraph, it doesn't simply butt lines together, but inserts a vertical space between them, computed on the basis of the current value of `\baselineskip`. However, when the sum of the depth of a line with the height of the following line is more than `\baselineskip`, TeX inserts `\lineskip`.

In this case, due to the fact that all lines contain very high pictures, between any two lines in that single paragraph will have `\lineskip` between them. Increasing (locally) the value of `\lineskip` (default 1pt) does the trick of separating them.

Comment: @Mico Why? Try the same code with `20ex` instead of `1ex`. It's `\lineskip`, not `\parskip`.

Comment: @Mico I added some words about `\lineskip`.

Comment: Thanks. That's great. I understand that subfigure is old - but it seems the easiest to use for this sort of thing? Is there an alternative that's just as simple?

Comment: @James Either `subfig` (which changes `\subfigure` into `\subfloat`) or `subcaption`.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't indicated *how* the last two subfigures should be placed, so I'll assume that they should be centered. This may be achieved by providing three `\hspace*{\fill}` instructions in the final row. (Rows 1 and 2 require only two `\hspace*{\fill}` instructions.)

Note that the `subfigure` package and its macros are deprecated. In the example below, I load the `subcaption` package instead and I use that package's `subfigure` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  % remove "demo" option in real document
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}

%% first row
\begin{subfigure}{.25\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{AR06_RUN03_vort.png}
\caption{AM06}\label{fig:AM06}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{.25\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{AR07_RUN03_vort.png}
\caption{AM07}\label{fig:AM07}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{.25\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{AR08_run03_vort.png}
\caption{AM09}\label{fig:AM08}
\end{subfigure}

%% second row
\medskip  %% add a bit of vertical separation from previous row
\begin{subfigure}{.25\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{AR09_run03_vort.png}
\caption{AM09}\label{fig:AM09}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{.25\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{AR10_run03_vort.png}
\caption{AM10}\label{fig:AM10}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{.25\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{AR11_run03_vort.png}
\caption{AM11}\label{fig:AM11}
\end{subfigure}

%% final row
\medskip
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{.25\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{AR12_run03_vort.png}
\caption{AM12}\label{fig:AM12}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{.25\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{AR13_run03_vort.png}
\caption{AM13}\label{fig:AM13}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't advertise `\null`; most of all, don't use it yourself if you don't know what it does. Your first usage of `\null` is in vertical mode, so it does *nothing at all* (except perhaps some damage). Try without it and see.

Comment: @egreg - Many thanks for pointing out this issue. Indeed, the output is the exactly the same without the first `\null` instruction.

Comment: And now, `\hfill\null` should be `\hspace*{\fill}`: the latter is documented, the former isn't.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks for this. I've replaced all `\hfill` instructions with `\hspace*{\fill}` and have gotten rid of the last `\null` directive.