# subfigures in subfigmatrix

Tags: floats, matrices, subfloats

I want to place 5 subpictures, 3 on the first row, two in the second one. The last two have to be of the same dimensions of the first three but cenetered (I mean both of them near the centre of the page, not at the extremes).

```
\begin{figure}[H]

\begin{subfigmatrix}{3}
    \subfigure[$\mathbb{P}^2$]{\includegraphics{Chapter3/Immagini/RSB/p2.png}}
    \subfigure[$\mathbb{P}^4$]{\includegraphics{Chapter3/Immagini/RSB/p4.png}}
    \subfigure[$\mathbb{P}^6$]{\includegraphics{Chapter3/Immagini/RSB/p6.png}}
    \subfigure[$\mathbb{P}^8$]{\includegraphics{Chapter3/Immagini/RSB/p8.png}}
    \subfigure[$\mathbb{P}^{10}$]{\includegraphics{Chapter3/Immagini/RSB/p10.png}}
\end{subfigmatrix}
\caption{RSB -- $\theta'$ contours , $\mathbb{P}^{2,4,6,8,10}$ solutions on a mesh of $2\,400$ elements using the Godunov flux.}
\label{fig:rsb}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: Completely unrelated to your question, but your images are beautiful. They would make a very nice wall paper :)

Comment: You would make it easier to answer your question, if you would include a small, but compilable text document including all the necessary packages etc.

Answer (score 3):

My idea is stolen from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207302/237192). Seems like `subfigmatrix` uses `\hfill` to do the spacing between the subfigures. Here we locally change `\hfill` to `\hspace{0.1cm}`, so you have always 0.1cm space between your subfigures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigmat,etoolbox,amssymb,float}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\patchcmd{\subfigmatrix}{\hfill}{\hspace{0.2cm}}{}{}
\begin{subfigmatrix}{3}
    \subfigure[$\mathbb{P}^2$]{\includegraphics{example-image}}
    \subfigure[$\mathbb{P}^4$]{\includegraphics{example-image}}
    \subfigure[$\mathbb{P}^6$]{\includegraphics{example-image}}
    \subfigure[$\mathbb{P}^8$]{\includegraphics{example-image}}
    \subfigure[$\mathbb{P}^{10}$]{\includegraphics{example-image}}
\end{subfigmatrix}
\caption{RSB -- $\theta'$ contours , $\mathbb{P}^{2,4,6,8,10}$ solutions on a mesh of $2\,400$ elements using the Godunov flux.}
\label{fig:rsb}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

---

### Another Idea

Just to offer you another idea: You can try `subcaption`'s `\subcaptionbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{$\mathbb{P}^2$}[0.3\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}
    \subcaptionbox{$\mathbb{P}^4$}[0.3\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}
    \subcaptionbox{$\mathbb{P}^6$}[0.3\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}
    \subcaptionbox{$\mathbb{P}^8$}[0.3\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}
    \subcaptionbox{$\mathbb{P}^{10}$}[0.3\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}
\caption{RSB -- $\theta'$ contours , $\mathbb{P}^{2,4,6,8,10}$ solutions on a mesh of $2\,400$ elements using the Godunov flux.}
\label{fig:rsb}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result (subcaptionbox)]

Answer (score 1):

The `subfigmat` package uses `subfigure` that has been obsolete for about 20 years.

Here's a similar approach, with `subfig`. Some trick is necessary because `\subfloat` ignores spaces after it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb,subfig}
\usepackage{showframe}

\NewCommandCopy\ORIsubfloat\subfloat
\NewDocumentCommand{\NEWsubfloat}{om}{%
  \begingroup\setlength{\spaceskip}{0pt}%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{\ORIsubfloat[#1]{#2}}{\ORIsubfloat{#2}}%
  \endgroup\space\ignorespaces
}

\newlength{\subfloatmatrixwidth}
\newenvironment{subfloatmatrix}[2][0.2cm]{%
  \centering
  \setlength{\subfloatmatrixwidth}{%
    \dimexpr(\columnwidth-(#1)*\numexpr(#2-1)\relax)/(#2)\relax
  }%
  \setlength{\spaceskip}{#1 minus 1pt}%
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=\subfloatmatrixwidth}%
  \setlength{\lineskip}{\medskipamount}%
  \RenewCommandCopy\subfloat\NEWsubfloat
}{\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\begin{subfloatmatrix}{3}
    \subfloat[$\mathbb{P}^2$]{\includegraphics{example-image}}
    \subfloat[$\mathbb{P}^4$]{\includegraphics{example-image}}
    \subfloat[$\mathbb{P}^6$]{\includegraphics{example-image}} 
    \subfloat[$\mathbb{P}^8$]{\includegraphics{example-image}}
    \subfloat[$\mathbb{P}^{10}$]{\includegraphics{example-image}}
\end{subfloatmatrix}
\caption{RSB -- $\theta'$ contours , $\mathbb{P}^{2,4,6,8,10}$ solutions on 
  a mesh of $2\,400$ elements using the Godunov flux.}
\label{fig:rsb}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The environment has also an optional argument for the separation between subfloats, default 0.2cm.

[image]

The same, but with

```
\begin{subfloatmatrix}[0.5cm]{3}
```

[image]